# Cloudmade Web Maps API Geocoding Issue

Tags: geocoding, api, maps, web, cloudmade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cloudmade Web Maps API  Marker Clustering problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27068/cloudmade-web-maps-api-marker-clustering-problem)

I'm at Geocoding in Cloudmade Web Maps API. I've the code below. Whenever I try to access the page, `content of elements must consist of well-formed character...` trace is generated, and the page does not render.

My environment is Apache Tomcat 7, and JSF.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tile.cloudmade.com/wml/latest/web-maps-lite.js"></script>
  <title>CloudMade Geocoding</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="cm-example" style="width: 700px; height: 500px">
 <div id="panel" style="width: 200px; float: left; padding-left: 10px"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new CM.Map('cm-example', new CM.Tiles.CloudMade.Web({key: 'API_KEY'}));

  var geocoder = new CM.Geocoder('API_KEY');

  geocoder.getLocations('London Bridge, London', function(response) {
    var southWest = new CM.LatLng(response.bounds[0][0], response.bounds[0][1]),
        northEast = new CM.LatLng(response.bounds[1][0], response.bounds[1][1]);

    map.zoomToBounds(new CM.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));

    for (var i = 0; i < response.features.length; i++) {
        var coords = response.features[i].centroid.coordinates,
            latlng = new CM.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);

        var marker = new CM.Marker(latlng, {
            title: response.features[i].properties.name
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've, of course, replaced the API_KEY with my actual API key, which works with the rest of the examples. Is anyone able to spot what I may be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.